# I can't get my timer to go faster for testing

Tags: actionscript-3

Hey guys i am trying to get this countdown timer to go faster so i can test it when it goes to the next level etc... but i am playing around with the numbers but its not work :(

please if you guys can comment what you are doing im new to programming and it helping me

```
package {
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class CountdownTimer extends Timer {

    public var time:Number = 0;

    public function CountdownTimer(time:Number = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, delay:Number = 1000) {
        super(delay, repeatCount);

        if (isNaN(time)) {
            this.time = 0;
        }
        else {
            this.time = time;
        }
        repeatCount = Math.ceil(time / delay);
    }
```

to start the timer

```
    override public function start():void {
        super.start();

        addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
        addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);
    }
```

to reset the timer

```
    override public function reset():void {
        super.reset();
        time = 0;

    }

    protected function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
        time -= delay;
        if(time == 0){
        trace("time = 0")
        }
        trace("delay");
        trace(time);
    }
```

this par is for timer complete

```
    protected function timerCompleteHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {

    }
```

to stop the timer

```
    override public function stop():void {
        super.stop();

        removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
        removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What is the point of your `time` var?  Or maybe a better question is what is the point of this custom class that extends timer?  What are you trying to accomplish? If you want a timer to go faster, just decrease it's delay.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var timer:Timer = null;

    timer = new Timer(delay);
    timer.addEventListener(Timer.TimerEvent, _OnTimerFire);

   private function _OnTimerFire(e:TimerEvent) : void {
     // do stuff
   }
```

The delay is the number of milliseconds after which the timer will be revoked. I am not sure why do you have to subclass the timer class.

Comment: I want to create a poker tournament app and its a countdown timer an other guy on stack overflow wrote this call for me but i didn't get why its like this i had wrote something i guess easier